# How to trigger a file download with Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating an application to browse and download recordings of phone calls.

Part of this application is a table populated with an *ngFor to display the recordings and associated information. Each row on the table also has a checkbox used to mark the recording for download. I have gotten to the point where I can console.log the links to the test mp3s that I am using, but I cannot figure out how to actually trigger the downloading of said mp3s.

I would really like to be able to do this using Typescript and without the use of jQuery.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isAllChecked()" (change)="checkAll($event)"> </th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Calling Number</th>
                <th>Called Number</th>
                <th> </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let entry of recordingsList">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="entry.isSelected"> </td>
                <td>{{entry.date}}</td>
                <td>{{entry.time}}</td>
                <td>{{entry.duration}}</td>
                <td>{{entry.callingNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{entry.calledNumber}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button (click)="openPlayer(entry)" class="play-button"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

-

```
// Download selected recordings

    downloadSelected() {
        let isSelected = this.recordingsList.filter(x => x.isSelected);
        isSelected.forEach(x => console.log(x.audio));
    }
```

-

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) has a `download` attribute.

Comment: @PavelStaselun I am aware of the download attribute for <a> tags. But I don't see how that can be applied to my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question directly, you can open new tab for every link:

```
downloadSelected() {
        let isSelected = this.recordingsList.filter(x => x.isSelected);
        isSelected.forEach(x => window.open(x.audio, '_blank'));
    }
```

However, this is not graceful in terms user experience with multiple tabs opening up wildly. So I suggest you to create special url (ex: example.com/bulk-download?ids=1,34,56) that creates zip folder with selected files and lets the user to download

Comment: Thank you for the help! But, there are two problems that prevent this from completely fulfilling my need. It opens the selected mp3 in a new window, while I need the file to begin downloading when the user clicks the download button. Also, this does not open all selected recordings. It seems to only be opening the first one.

Comment: Technically, you could create multiple anchor elements on fly and trigger click event on them. However, this is not reliable due to browser restrictions and it is not angular way. So, the right solution would be to create compressed file on backend.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem like a very clean solution. I was hoping that I could do this in Angular, but it's looking more and more like it's simply not possible and I'm going to need my back-end dev to create a zip of the selected files and a link to it that I can href to. :(